# Hiding nodes in a TreeView

Tags: silverlight, treeview, silverlight-5.0

Lets say we have the following collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes
```

The `Node` class has the Following collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Leaf> Leaves
```

where the `Leaf` class has a `DependencyProperty` named `IsActive`.

I would like to display this data in a `TreeView`, however, I only want active leaves (a `Leaf` object where `IsActive` is `True`) to be displayed under their parent `Node`. That is, I want inactive leaves to not be displayed. I would also like nodes with no visible leaves to be hidden as well. I currently have the data displayed using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, but I don't know how to hide the described nodes. I have tried changing the `Content` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, but the the collapsing arrow (`ItemContainer`) is still visible.

Is there a way to achieve this? or do I just need to change the data structure?
Let me know if I need to add more information or clarify something.

**Update:**
I guess I need to clarify that I understand that I can just change `Node` and `Leaf` to achieve what I am looking for, but I would like to know if I have to do it that way. I would like to be able to use templating, styling, etc. (some xaml tricks) to achieve my desired view.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, how about using *linq* to filter the `Nodes` collection? Then set the new collection as the datasource of your `TreeView. Smth like:

```
var ActiveNodes = Nodes.Where(p => p.Leaves.Any( l = l.IsActive == true));
```

**Edit:** *Filtering during binding*

I still think the first solution is the way to go but if you you might find this suggestion useful too. Change the `Node` class to:

```
    class Node
    {
        public bool IsActiveNode 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return Leaves.Any(p => p.IsActive);
            }             
        }
        //Other stuff.. 
        public ObservableCollection<Leaf> Leaves { get; set; }        
    }
```

Then you can use a converter (see an example of converters [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/) in case you are not familiar) to try to show/hide the nodes.

```
<toolkit:TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
    <toolkit:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <toolkit:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsActiveNode , Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" ></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </toolkit:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </toolkit:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:TreeView>
```

If you are worried about the performance of the first approach, I donT think latter is any better :) Maybe there s a better way, if so it d be nice to know.

**EDIT 2** *To answer your question*

> I would like to know if I have to do it that way.

I think you have to change the bound source in runtime (1) or introduce a new property to the `Node` like the *IsActive* in the `Leaf`  (2)

Comment: I realize that I can get this functionality by changing the data structure (creating extra collections and updating them every time the `IsActive` property changes), but I rather not. I want the view to update through data binding on the current data structure.

Comment: I don't think you understand what my issue is still. I am fully capable of changing the data structures (Node and Leaf) to achieve what I am looking to do, but that's not my question. Also, neither of your suggestions would work anyways. `IsActive` is a `DependencyProperty` for a reason. It changes during run-time and the `TreeView` will have to update accordingly.

Comment: I apologize if I came across unappreciative, that was not my intention. All of your solutions thus far would require manual updates every time a single `IsActive` property changed. If there was a way to use templating (xaml) and bind the `Visibility` of the `TreeView` items to the property instead, then no manual updates would be required. That's what I am looking for, but I don't know how to go about doing it. The `Visibility` property that I think I need to bind to is in the `TreeViewItem`, but its not accessible in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.